# Instead of image click onItemClick get called in listview when I press image and before my finger up notifydatasetchanged get called

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have Listview for newsfeeds like facebook and in that listview have images, detail and comment. I have implemented onItemClick on listview whole item and images and comments have individual click listeners. They are working fine but sometime when I click image and during that click notifydatasetchanged get called, onItemClick get called instead of image click.

Comment: show your code ,I can it more carefully

Comment: it contains above 1000 line of code and have multiple files.

Comment: you can write the image and comments click event in the adapter

Comment: @guobao  One list Item have multiple views, and some views have their individual click listeners. But when I press and hold a view which have own click listener, During finger down if notifyDataSetChanged get called and I left up my finger it calls onItemClick instead of pressed view click listener. And normally its working fine. I hope now you can get my point.